# Firefox becomes unkillable, waiting on AFD driver, any suggestions?

Tags: windows-7, drivers

Is anyone else having this problem?

Both Skype and Firefox are freezing and becoming unkillable due to "\Driver\AFD".

I'll open Firefox and it won't work, it just sits there, "Connecting...", then I'll try and close it and the process will become unkillable.  If I use the steps on the ["unkillable processes"](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2005/08/17/unkillable-processes.aspx) blog post by Mark Russinovich I find the IRP belongs to "\Driver\AFD", which I believe is the Ancillary Function Driver for WinSock.

I thought this was only a Firefox issue, but now Skype is also becoming unkillable when I try to close it, and I find it's the same "\Driver\AFD" causing the problem.

```
THREAD fffffa80073c7060  Cid 0c1c.1214  Teb: 000000007ef8f000 
Win32Thread: 0000000000000000 
WAIT: (Executive) KernelMode Non-Alertable
fffff88009907840  NotificationEvent
IRP List:
fffffa8007b6e670: (0006,0310) Flags: 00000404  Mdl: 00000000
...
Owning Process            fffffa80079c9060       Image:         Skype.exe


0: kd> !irp fffffa8007b6e670
Irp is active with 4 stacks 4 is current (= 0xfffffa8007b6e818)
 No Mdl: No System Buffer: Thread fffffa80073c7060:  Irp stack trace.
     cmd  flg cl Device   File     Completion-Context
...
>[ 12, 0]   0  0 fffffa8007b5b670 fffffa8007adf2f0 00000000-00000000
               \Driver\AFD
                        Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

I've seen the suggestions on Microsoft Support suggesting that I just replace afd.sys.  But does anyone know what's causing this?  Is anyone else having this issue?

Comment: AFD is related to your networking stack (as witnessed by the reference to Winsock).  This jives with your problems in two heavily network-dependant programs.  If you're AFD.sys has become corrupted, then you should restore and/or replace it.  Otherwise, it's probably a network driver/adapter issue. Try updating your driver so the latest available from the manufacturer, if it doesn't help, try a new/different network adapter.

Comment: Beyond that, it's basically impossible for us to say for sure what's "causing it" based on the provided information, and asking if anyone else has this problem isn't a constructive question. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on one PC only. It first happened with pidgin and skype and since Firefox 36 it happens with Firefox. 
Mozilla should be aware of it: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1124880. There is also a workaround in comment #35.

I have 2 PCs with the same afd.sys files and it only happens on 1 PC. I even reinstalled windows and it still happens. So I guess this is a windows bug that should be reported.

This might be interesting, too. http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2005/08/17/unkillable-processes.aspx